# How to sort by name then date modification in BASH

Tags: linux, bash, sorting, unix

Lets say I have a folder of .txt files that have a `dd-MM-yyyy_HH-mm-ss` time followed by `_name.txt`. I want to be able to sort by name first then time after. Example:

**BEFORE**

- 15-2-2010_10-01-55_greg.txt
- 10-2-1999_10-01-55_greg.txt
- 10-2-1999_10-01-55_jason.txt

**AFTER**

- greg_1_10-2-1999_10-01-55
- greg_2_15-2-2010_10-01-55
- jason_1_10-2-1999_10-01-55

Edit: Apologies, from my "cp" line I was meant to copy them into another directory with a different name to them.

Something I tried to do is make a copy with the count, but it doesn't sort the files with the same name properly in terms of dates:

```
cd data/unfilteredNames
for filename in *.txt; do
    n=${filename%.*}
    n=${filename##*_}
    filteredName=${n%.*}
    count=0
    find . -type f -name "*_$n" | while read name; do 
        count=$(($count+1))
        cp -p $name ../filteredNames/"$filteredName"_"$count"
    done
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that the renaming of files is one of your expectation. At least for only sorting file name, you don't need to.

You can do this by only using GNU `sort` command:

```
sort -t- -k5.4 -k3.1,3.4 -k2.1,2.1 -k1.1,1.2 -k3.6,3.13 <(printf "%s\n" *.txt)
```

`-t` sets the field separator to a dash `-`.

`-k` enables to sort based on fields. As explained in `man sort` page, the syntax is `-k<start>,<stop>` where `<start>` or  is composed of `<field number>.<position>`. Adding several `-k` option to the command allows to sort on multiple fields; the first in he command line having more precedence than the other.

For example, the first `-k5.4` tells to sort based on the 5th fields with an offset of 4 characters. There isn't a stop field because this is the end of the filename.
The `-k3.1,3.4` option sorts based on the 3rd field starting from offset 1 to 4.
The same principle applies to other `-k` options.

In your example the month field only has 1 digit. If you have files with a month coded with 2 digits, you might want to pad with 0 all month filenames. This can be done by adding to the `printf` statement this `<(... | sed 's/-0\?\([0-9]\)/-0\1/')` and change the `-k 2.1,2.1` by `-k2.1,2.2`.